# Direct sums of presheaves and basis of topology

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{B} = (U_i)_i$ be a basis for its topology.
Let $F := \underset{i}{\bigoplus} F_i$ be a direct sum of presheaves on $X$. We denote by $F_{\mathcal{B}}$ its restriction to $\mathcal{B}$. We can sheafify this data on $\mathcal{B}$ to get a $\mathcal{B}$-sheaf $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{B}$. Moreover, there is an equivalence of categories between $\mathcal{B}$-sheaves and sheaves on $X$, and therefore we can construct a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ which agree with $\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{B}}$ on $\mathcal{B}$.

My question is the following: is $\mathcal{F}$ the sheafification of $F$, that is the direct sum (in the category of sheaves):
$$\mathcal{F} = \underset{i}{\bigoplus} \mathcal{F}_i,$$ with $\mathcal{F}_i$ being the sheafification of $F_i$ ?

In other words, does the functor (which is an equivalence of categories) $$Sh(X) \to Sh(\mathcal{B})$$ from the category of sheaves on $X$ to the category of $\mathcal{B}$-sheaves preserves direct sums ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Any equivalence preserves any limit and any colimit as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @asdq. Is there a reference where I can find this kind of results ?

Comment: This should be in any introduction to category theory. I recommend Emily Riehl: Category Theory in Context.

Comment: Thanks a lot @asdq.

Comment: Actually, a more general question should be: what types of functors between Abelian categories commute with limits and colimits ? For instance, given a closed subspace $Z \overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} X$, does the restriction functor $i^! : Sh(X) \to Sh(Z)$ satisfy this property ?

Comment: If you mean the inverse image functor $f^\ast$ (rather than the exceptional inverse image $f^!$ that acts on the derived categories) then this is true and it follows from $f^\ast$  being a left adjoint.

Comment: Yes, I meant the inverse image functor. I just saw the notation $i^!$ in http://rvirk.com/notes/topology2012/operations.pdf. I meant the sheaf on $Z$ defined as the restriction of the sheaf on $X$ to $Z$. Is that the inverse image, or am I confused because of all the notations ? Thanks again.